# Multiple WHEN in CASE only applies first two

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a CASE with 4 WHENs. The first two applie fine, but the last two (or any others I add past that) do not get applied. All WHENs are referring to the same field.

Here's what I'm trying to do. The field in question is formatted as:

```
[Indexname]_[Company]_[Product]_[StartDate$EndDate]
```

So it would look like

```
Retail_Walmart_Stores_Inc_Chair_03012012$05312015
```

The first Case I wrote was to eliminate the date

```
CASE WHEN FIELD1 LIKE '%$%' THEN REPLACE(FIELD1,RIGHT(FIELD1,17),'') ELSE FIELD1 END AS NewField
```

That works great. Then I want to remove the Index Name so I added a second WHEN. That worked also. But then, our company will have the full legal name of the company we're doing business (so "Wal-Mart Stores, Inc" or "The Walt Disney Company". For readability, I want those records to just say "WalMart" or Disney."

My new code reads as

```
CASE                                                                                             
   WHEN FIELD1 LIKE '%$%'                                                                        
     THEN REPLACE(FIELD1,RIGHT(FIELD1,17),'')                                                      
   WHEN FIELD LIKE '%RETAIL%'                                                                 
     THEN REPLACE(FIELD1,'RETAIL','')                                                            
   WHEN FIELD LIKE '%STORES_INC%'                                                                 
     THEN REPLACE(FIELD1,'STORES_INC','')                                                        
   WHEN FIELD LIKE '%THE_WALT_DISNEY_COMPANY%'                                                                 
     THEN REPLACE(FIELD1,'THE_WALT_DISNEY_COMPANY','DISNEY')                                                        
   ELSE FIELD1                                                                                    
   END AS NewField1
```

I don't understand why this stops working after the first two. At first I thought maybe it's because they are all referring to the first column, but then the second WHEN wouldn't have worked either.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: `WHEN FIELD LIKE '%RETAIL%` should be `WHEN FIELD LIKE '%RETAIL%'`. You're missing a closing single quote (`'`). Your latter lines also have the same problem.

Comment: Your sample is missing a few end quotes on your `LIKE` clauses. Ex: `LIKE '%RETAIL%` needs an ending quote

Comment: Uh... If your goal is to do multiple replaces at once, then you'd do something like `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(<insert logic here>...))))` instead of a case expression.

Comment: And assuming those errors are just typos, a case expression stops at the first match, so most likely its matched within the first 2 `when`s and therefore doesn't test any further.

Comment: You also refer to both `FIELD` and `FIELD1`. Please update your question to contain the actual code you are using, along with sample data and expected results i.e. make it a [mre]

Comment: CASE WHEN WHEN WHEN WHEN is like IF THEN ELSEIF ELSEIF ELSEIF.  It is not IF THEN ALSO ALSO ALSO.

Comment: It's **expected** things will stop at the **first** match. 

If you have potentially more than one operation, you need to **nest them**. And that can quickly become _extremely complicated_ if you have to list the same conditions across several possible `WHEN` clauses at each level.

Comment: @avery_larry Ahh ok that made it click in my mind. I was trying to avoid nesting the replaces because it becomes hard to read but I guess that’s just the way to go. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do *all* the replacements rather than just the first one:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CASE WHEN FIELD1 LIKE '%$%' THEN REPLACE(FIELD1, RIGHT(FIELD1, 17), '') ELSE FIELD1
                        END, 'RETAIL', ''
                       ), STORES_INC', ''
               ), 'THE_WALT_DISNEY_COMPANY', 'DISNEY'
       )  AS NewField1
```

A `case` expression stops at the first expression that evaluates to true.